# How To Make Parallel HTTP Requests

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a console app that makes a single request to a web page and returns its server status eg. 200, 404, etc..

I'd like to apply following changes:

**List of User Inputs:**

- Url to request
- How many parallel connections to use(concurrent users)
- How long(seconds) to submit as many requests as it can

**List of Outputs:**

- Show Total Fetches
- Show Fetches per Second
- Show Average Response Time (ms)

I imagine the best way to do it is to run multiple http fetches in parallel and run in a single process, so it doesn't bog down the client machine.

I really like C# but I'm still new to it. I've researched other articles about this but I don't fully understand them so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.10.1.6/64k.html");
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            //Returns "MovedPermanently", not 301 which is what I want.

            int i_goodResponse = (int)response.StatusCode;
            string s_goodResponse = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Normal Response: " + i_goodResponse + " " + s_goodResponse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            int i_badResponse = (int)((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
            string s_badResponse = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Error Response: " + i_badResponse + " " + s_badResponse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Some possible code that I found:

```
void StartWebRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = ...;
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), webRequest);
}

void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Comment: So you are looking to develop a console app to use for load testing of a website or similar?

Comment: If true, you have to be wary that the statistics you collect may actually be limited by the bandwidth (CPU and/or Network) of the client machine, rather than the web server you are testing, no matter how many requests you try to run in parallel

Comment: correct. That is precisely what I'm trying to do. The page in my sample is a 64kb html file. As for bandwidth, I'm on an intranet. I was just hoping for some code snippets that aren't so random...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a good place to make use of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx) in .NET 4.0. I have wrapped your code in a `Parallel.For` block which will execute a number of sets of requests in parallel, collate the total times in each parallel branch, and then calculate the overall result afterwards.

```
int n = 16;
int reqs = 10;

var totalTimes = new long[n];

Parallel.For(0, n, i =>
    {
        for (int req = 0; req < reqs; req++)
        {
            Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
            try
            {
                w.Start();

                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:42838/Default.aspx");
                webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

                w.Stop();
                totalTimes[i] += w.ElapsedMilliseconds;


                //Returns "MovedPermanently", not 301 which is what I want.            
                int i_goodResponse = (int)response.StatusCode;
                string s_goodResponse = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Normal Response: " + i_goodResponse + " " + s_goodResponse);
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                w.Stop();
                totalTimes[i] += w.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                int i_badResponse = (int)((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
                string s_badResponse = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Error Response: " + i_badResponse + " " + s_badResponse);
            }
        }
    });

var grandTotalTime = totalTimes.Sum();
var reqsPerSec = (double)(n * reqs * 1000) / (double)grandTotalTime;

Console.WriteLine("Requests per second: {0}", reqsPerSec);
```

The TPL is very useful here, as it abstracts away the detail of creating multiple threads of exececution within your process, and running each parallel branch on these threads.

Note that you still have to be careful here - we cannot share state which is updated during the tasks between threads, hence the array for `totalTimes` which collates the totals for each parallel branch, and only summed up at the very end, once the parallel execution is complete. If we didn't do this, we are open to the possibility of a race condition - where two seperate threads attempt to update the total count simultaneously, potentially corrupting the result.

I hope this makes sense and is useful as a start for you (I only calculate requests per second here, the other stats should be relatively easy to add). Add comments if you need further clarifications.

Comment: While using the following parameters I've encountered an Unhandled Exception within the catch block.

// n = n page fetches
int n = 100;
// reqs = parallel requests(concurrent users)
int reqs = 64;

Error line:
int i_badResponse = (int)((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;

Error Description: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.

My theory is I've reach the limit the server can support and now it is not responding or something similar. 

How can I catch and output this Exception?

Comment: check if we.Response is null before accessing we.Response.StatusCode - probably is some sort of client side timeout, hence no response coming back from the server

Comment: Perfect. Just to clarify. Is it safe to assume that, given variables n = 16 and reqs = to 10, I am in fact simulating 10 concurrent users requesting the page 16 times over and measuring the time it took to complete this task?

Comment: The other way around - 16 concurrent users. 10 requests. As I initially mentioned though - be careful as the limitation may well be the client machine rather than the server, so if you can, it may be better to run on 2 or 3 client PCs simultaneously

Comment: 10 requests per user * 16 = 160 total requests.

Comment: Chris, after some testing I noticed the following: 1024 users & 1 requests = 13ms avg. BUT! 1 users & 1024 requests = 1100ms avg. // What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to clarify is that 1 user can only really make 1 request per click. Could this mean that 1024 users & 1 requests = 13ms avg. is the most accurate test to run?

Comment: Those figures don't add up - you may want to try logging the per-request times, just for one run, to see whether there are anomolies driving such a high average request length

Comment: Perhaps I should tell you just how I am calculating the avg request time. Maybe it is incorrect. Here's what I've done: var avgResponseTime = Math.Round((totalTimes.Average()));

Comment: totalTimes is the per-parallel total times, so if you only run 1 in parallel, with 1024 requests, totalTimes will just be 1 in length and have the total of the 1024 requests, so you need Math.Round(totalTimes.Average() / reqs) - which should be about 1ms in your example

Comment: so totalTimes is a long array with its length set by the amount of concurrent users where each array index is populated with the individual time it took to complete 1 request or 1 set of requests?

Comment: the reason for this is to prevent race conditions (where multiple threads update a single variable and corrupt each other). So when we run more than one concurrent task (the bit inside Parallel.For) we keep a seperate total for everything in that (ie for the set of requests)

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question, you can use BeginGetResponse to start async request.

Another, and more convenient method might be using WebClient class, if you are more familiar with events then with AsyncResult.

[DownloadDataCompletedEventHandlerd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.downloaddatacompletedeventhandler.aspx)